# connecting 2 android emulators as a server and a client using tcp sockets

Tags: android, sockets

I want to connect 2 emulator instances so that I would be able to send simple chat messages between them. For this I set up a server on one emulator and made other emulator a client. So I ran the server on emulator 5554 and the client on 5556.

Server Side Code listening on port 6000 :

```
public class NewServerActivity extends Activity{
//private TextView tv; 
private Thread fst;
private ServerSocket ss;
public static final int SERVERPORT = 6000; 
String mClientMsg = "";
protected static final int MSG_ID = 0x1337;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    tv.setText("Nothing from client yet");
    this.fst= new Thread(new RunThread()); 
    this.fst.start();
}

protected void onStop() {
      super.onStop();
      try {
         // make sure you close the socket upon exiting
         ss.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

Handler myUpdateHandler = new Handler() {
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
         switch (msg.what) {
         case MSG_ID:
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
            tv.setText(mClientMsg);
            break;
         default:
            break;
         }
         super.handleMessage(msg);
      }
   };

class RunThread implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        try{
            ss= new ServerSocket(); 
            Socket s= ss.accept();
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

            Message m = new Message();
            m.what = MSG_ID;
            String st = null;
            st = input.readLine();
            mClientMsg = st;
            myUpdateHandler.sendMessage(m);

        }catch(IOException ep){
            ep.printStackTrace();
        }       

    }       
}
```

}

Client side code establishing connection on port 5000:

```
    public class NewClientActivity extends Activity {
private Button bt;
private TextView tv;
private Socket socket;
private Thread scd;
private String serverIpAddress = "10.0.2.2";
private static final int REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT = 5000;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);      
     bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
     tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
     this.scd= new Thread(new RunThread1()); 
     this.scd.start();
}

class RunThread1 implements Runnable{
    public void run() {
        try {
             //InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
             socket = new Socket(serverIpAddress, REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT);
          } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();
          }

        bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                   EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
                   String str = et.getText().toString();
                   PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                         new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                         true);
                   out.println(str);
                   Log.d("Client", "Client sent message");                     

                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                   tv.setText("Error1");
                   e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                   tv.setText("Error2");
                   e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                   tv.setText("Error3");
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
             }
          });
        }       
}
```

}

I redirected the ports as :

```
     telnet localhost 5554
     redir add tcp:5000:6000
```

Everything works fine, both the apps start but when I click the send button there is no response on the server side.Am I missing something.